# Attack on Many Time Pad

Tags: one-time-pad, ciphertext-only-attack

I have 7 ciphertexts that have been XORed with the same key. I'm writing a program to figure out what the plaintexts are and possibly maybe recover the key.

I have managed to convert the HEX ciphertexts (1-7) into binary and XOR each ciphertext with each other:

- C1 XOR (C2...C7)
- C2 XOR (C3...C7)
- C3 XOR (C4...C7)
- C4 XOR (C5...C7)
- C5 XOR (C6...C7)
- C6 XOR C7

Which in return I get a stream for each operation S(1...21) for which I converted back to HEX.

After getting the streams, I'm not sure what to do next. Knowing that after I XORed the ciphertexts together, I have removed the key from the equation and I am left with m1 XOR m2. But I'm not sure how to use this stream to my advantage as an attacker to recover the messages.

I have even attempted trying something simple on paper but I just don't quite understand it.

Comment: Search for Crib and dragging. Guess one word see that reveal some meaningful in the others.

Comment: [A Natural Language Approach to Automated Cryptanalysis of Two-time Pads, ,mason at al. 2006](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~jason/papers/mason+al.ccs06.pdf)